# how to tell when you've reached the end of a C array? (specifically argv)

Tags: c, argv, argc

been asked a question on this, basically coming up with argc...without actually having argc

if your given argv, which as I understand essentially a array of pointers to the relevant char arrays of each inputted argument,

how would I actually go about counting the number of pointers in argv?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C standard specifies:

```
argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.
```

So you can always detect the end by testing for `0`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't, unless the array is specifically terminated by some "stop" value like `0` or `NULL`. This is the reason `argc` exists. Pointers themselves don't *have* a length/count/number of elements associated with them.

When passing around pointers to arrays, you must necessarily also pass in the number of elements or explicitly allocate one-too-many elements and add a "null" element to the end of the array.

Comment: @JensGustedt Read again please. I *specifically* said "In general", and answered in the context of *all arrays*, not specifically `argv`.

Comment: @meegar, well, well, then your second phrase has not much context to refer to. `argc` exists for convenience (or tradition) and would strictly speaking not be necessary.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the pattern of a zero(or whatsoever)-terminated array, which makes it *unecessary* to carry around a size descriptor with it.

Comment: This answer doesn't fit the question. OP is asking about arg{v,c}, not "all arrays"

Comment: @RobertMartin Actually, OP asked about "C arrays" specifically argv. My answer covers both. Read the title of the question: *"how to tell when you've reached the end of a C array? (specifically argv)"*

Comment: Perhaps the answer should be updated to reflect that, though this answer is generally right, it is wrong in the current context.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with some people here.

argv itself is null terminated. For example, if you type

```
$./foobar hello strawberry
```

you'll get

```
argv = [%p]  [%p]  [%p]  [NULL]
        |     |     |    
        |     |      \_"strawberry\0"
        |     | 
        |      \_"hello\0"
        |    
         \_"./foobar\0"
```

In other words, this sort of code will work:

```
while (*argv) {
    printf("%s\n", *argv);
    argv++;
}
```

Try it and see!

Comment: You may be right about it ending in a NULL per Jens comment, but assuming that it will be a NULL without knowing the standard is a bad idea.

Comment: [app.execve.01.02](http://linuxtesting.org/results/lsb_reqs?showreqs=execve) "argv: the application shall ensure that the last member of this array is a null pointer."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. After the array ends there is randomness, and you cannot accurately distinguish randomness from real data.

Answer (score 0):

You must use argc, which is always present when argv is furnished. The final char pointer in argv is at argv[argc-1]